# Android Studio 4.0 Emulator Black Screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Suddenly my Android Emulator stopped working and it shows only black screen. I tried ADB devices with cmd and it says device offline. My Android Stuido version 4.0 . Intel HAXM version 7.5.6 . Android Emulator version 30.0.12 . I also tried this command in cmd --> "emulator -avd Pixel_3a_API_28 -gpu host". then it says " emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Critical: UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect failed for ptDst=(1429, 210), size=(300x21), dirty=(300x21 0, 0) (A device attached to the system is not functioning.) ((null):0, (null)) ". I also tried changing quick boot to cold boot in virtual device verify configuration. Tried changing android system image to lolipop, marshmallow. Tried changing avd device to pixel, nexus, generic devices and tablets. Non of them worked. Is there anyone who can give me a solution for the problem? My device has seperate VGA(GTX 1050ti). Windows version  Windows 10 V2004.[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Emulator has a lot of problems since the last update. I got the same problem and I tried to solve it in many ways , and it worked suddenly and stopped working 2 days later.

Until they make it work properly I advise you use Genymotion or a regular phone.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem had happened with me ....In my case the problem was about selection of wrong system image file .I had installed R (Api level 30) x86 for my emulator but it starts giving me problems so instead i installed R(Api Level 30)x86_64 for my emulator and fixed all . Make sure you install x86_64 system image file and give a try

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227) https://stackoverflow.com/a/68268166/7733418